# How to vertically justify in Bootstrap 4 columns

Tags: bootstrap-4

I have this structure:

```
<div class=”row”>
    <div class=”col”>
        <div class=”float-to-top”></div>
        <div class=”float-to-bottom></div>
    </div>

    <div class=”col”>
        <div class=”float-to-top”></div>
        <div class=”float-to-bottom></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The task is to align the divs of the same class with each other. Being Bootstrap 4, both columns are the same height, for free; and I can align the tops or the bottoms. But how to "justify" vertically?

Oh, and using media queries is not allowed; only the Bootstrap facilities.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Can you clarify the question and post a minimal example that demonstrates the issue? What do you mean by "justify"? Do you mean vertically centered?

Comment: you know how, when you center, say, text, horizontally, the text is surrounded by any extra whitespace, as needed. When you justify the same text, the extra whitespace is inside the text, between words; there is no whitespace outside the string.

Comment: Sorry, didn't realise I'm not supposed to press Enter. Same idea here: I need the first div in each column to start at the top of the column; the bottom div end at the bottom of the column; if the top divs are of different height, the whitespace be between the top div and the bottom div.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you want to swap rows and columns. So that your two `.col` classes sit next to each other, and your `.float-to-top` are at the top (with `.float-to-bottom` at the bottom).

If that's the case you're looking for the following on `.col`:

- `display: flex` to make use of flexbox
- `flex-direction: column` to swap the layout
- `justify-content: space-between` to space the elements out (top and bottom)
- a `height` to add the space in between the elements

And possibly:

- `align-items: center` for horizontal centering

This can be seen in the following:

```css
.col {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  height: 180px;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col">
    <div class="float-to-top">Top 1</div>
    <div class="float-to-bottom">Bottom 1</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <div class="float-to-top">Top 2</div>
    <div class="float-to-bottom">Bottom 2</div>
  </div>
</div>
```